# modules in an imported @ngModule aren't being picked up

Tags: angular

I have a main @ngModule that looks like this:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AccountCreateComponent} from './account/create/account-create.component';
import {AccountListComponent} from './account/list/account-list.component';
import {AccountUpdateComponent} from './account/update/account-update.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {LeaveCreateComponent} from './leave/create/leave-create.component';
import {LeaveListComponent} from './leave/list/leave-list.component';

import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {RestApiService} from "./rest-api.service";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {LeavePendingListComponent} from './leave/pending-list/leave-pending-list.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material";
import {MaterialModule} from "./MaterialModule";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AccountCreateComponent,
    AccountUpdateComponent,
    AccountListComponent,
    LeaveCreateComponent,
    LeaveListComponent,
    LeavePendingListComponent,
    MaterialModule,
      MatTableDataSource
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
      MatTableDataSource,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [RestApiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have a separate ngModule (called MaterialModule) that looks like this:

```
import {
    MatAutocompleteModule, MatButtonModule, MatButtonToggleModule, MatCardModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule, MatDialogModule, MatExpansionModule, MatGridListModule, MatIconModule, MatInputModule,
    MatListModule, MatMenuModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule, MatRippleModule, MatSelectModule, MatSidenavModule, MatSliderModule, MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule, MatStepperModule, MatTableModule, MatTabsModule, MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule
} from "@angular/material";
import {A11yModule} from "@angular/cdk/a11y";
import {BidiModule} from "@angular/cdk/bidi";
import {ObserversModule} from "@angular/cdk/observers";
import {OverlayModule} from "@angular/cdk/overlay";
import {PlatformModule} from "@angular/cdk/platform";
import {PortalModule} from "@angular/cdk/portal";
import {ScrollDispatchModule} from "@angular/cdk/scrolling";
import {CdkStepperModule} from "@angular/cdk/stepper";
import {CdkTableModule} from "@angular/cdk/table";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material";
/**
 * Created by maurice on 22-11-2017.
 */
@NgModule({
    exports: [
        // CDK
        // A11yModule,
        // BidiModule,
        // ObserversModule,
        // OverlayModule,
        // PlatformModule,
        // PortalModule,
        // ScrollDispatchModule,
        // CdkStepperModule,
        CdkTableModule,

        // Material
        MatPaginatorModule,
        // MatAutocompleteModule,
        // MatButtonModule,
        // MatButtonToggleModule,
        // MatCardModule,
        // MatCheckboxModule,
        // MatChipsModule,
        // MatDatepickerModule,
        // MatDialogModule,
        // MatExpansionModule,
        // MatGridListModule,
        // MatIconModule,
        // MatInputModule,
        // MatListModule,
        // MatMenuModule,
        // MatProgressBarModule,
        // MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        // MatRadioModule,
        // MatRippleModule,
        // MatSelectModule,
        // MatSidenavModule,
        // MatSlideToggleModule,
        // MatSliderModule,
        // MatSnackBarModule,
        // MatStepperModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTableDataSource,
        // MatTabsModule,
        // MatToolbarModule,
        // MatTooltipModule,
        // MatNativeDateModule,
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

You can clearly see that MatTableDataSource is being imported by MaterialModule. Yet when I run the application I get the following error:

```
Can't export value MatTableDataSource from MaterialModule as it was neither declared nor imported!
```

Which is very confusing since MatTableDataSource is being exported by MaterialModule and thus imported by the appModule. I've also added the MatTableDataSource directly to the imports of appModule but that doesn't solve anything either. Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong? This should work..

Comment: In the MaterialModule, add the elements that you export into the imports array

Answer (score 0):

Modules needs to be in `imports`, not `exports`

```
imports: [
   CdkTableModule,
   MatPaginatorModule,
   MatTableModule,
   MatTableDataSource
]
```

And do remove `node_modules` and then hit `npm install`.

Comment: this setup is giving me this error 'Can't export value MatTableDataSource from MaterialModule as it was neither declared nor imported!'

Comment: @Maurice, Sorry , please check now , it should work :)

Comment: now i'm getting this error: " Unexpected value 'MatTableDataSource' imported by the module 'MaterialModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation." Could this be a bug in angular or something? I updated all components to the most recent version yesterday

Comment: how do I remove node_modules? Do I have to search for it in a folder or is there an npm command I can use? Sorry I'm very new to Angular

Comment: just delete that folder , it will be in root directory of app